# How can I manipulate a new window in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension to allow users to login to social media sites from a single page. I am able to create a new incognito window but am unable to manipulate anything inside of the window that I created. I want to create an onload function for the new window to execute jquery. Thanks for getting me pointed in the right direction!

Comment: have you tried script injection with call back of tab create/update()?

Comment: I have not but I'm not sure where to start with that. Any good resources you can point me to?

Comment: If you want to manipulate incognito, you have to ask the user to check "Allow in incognito" under your extension in the settings

Comment: @ChrisJenkins: Check my answer and let me know if you questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer the following demonstration for manipulation of new incognito [window](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#type-Window) created and injecting some jquery into it.

### `References`

- [Windows](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html) API
- [Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html) API
- [Background Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)
- [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)
- [Manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html).

#### `manifest file`

This is used to bind permissions and register background pages to extension.Ensure it has all permissions needed.

```
{
"name":"Hanlder for Incognito window",
"description":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044338",
"version":"1",
"manifest_version":2,
"background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
},
"permissions":["tabs","http://www.google.co.in/"]
}
```

#### `background.js`

Inject jquery into new incognito window, from background page.

```
var _tabId_To_Look_For;

// Create a new incognito Window with some arbitary URL and give it focus
chrome.windows.create({
    "url": "http://www.google.co.in/",
    "focused": true,
    "incognito": true
}, function (window) {
    // Trace tab id which is created with this query 
    _tabId_To_Look_For = window.tabs[0].id
});

// Add an event Listener for new tab created
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // Inject script into chosen tab after it is loaded completely
    if (tabId == _tabId_To_Look_For && changeInfo.status == "complete") {
        // Inject Jquery and in current tab
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
            "file": "jquery.js"
        }, function () {
            // I am in call back
            console.log("Injected some jquery ");
        });
    }
});
```

Ensure you have enabled incognito access.

[image]

### `Output`

You will observe a new window with jquery injected.

Comment: And today I just learned how to inject scripts to tabs using that `file` option, thanks!